# Syntax Parser Strange Output

Tags: support, bug, syntax-highlighting

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234134/efficiently-run-hash-collision-checker) I am seeing strange output for the code syntax. The first part of the number in the variable `$num` is red, while the rest of it is not. A number formatted by this is allowable in PHP 7.4.  See the attached image.

[image]

As a comparison, I am placing the code here:

```php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

$result = [];

$num = 100_000_000_000;
$salt = 'some random salt';


for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++)  
    $result[crc32($salt.$i)] = true;

if (count($result) != $num)
    echo 'Collision'.PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Ok'.PHP_EOL;
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax parser?

Comment: I believe the bug report should be aimed at the library, SO doesn't manage it.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. There isn't anything we can do. You can file a bug with Prettify, or even submit a pull request, but that library is de facto unmaintaned. There are pull requests pending for *years*, including one of my own. And then even in the unlikely event that your change gets merged into Prettify upstream, SE would still have to update their version of Prettify to the latest. I *might* be able to pester a dev into doing that if the new version of Prettify didn't significantly increase the code size.

Comment: @CodyGray understood. I wasn't surer about the source for the highlighter.

Comment: This is specific and targetting PHP 7.4. I feel that there should be a tag for questions like this.